# Python Client - C++ Server Connection Refused Error

Tags: python, c++, linux, sockets, networking

So I'm trying to run a client-server application using Python as the client and C++ as the server.

The two are on separate machines - right now I'm running the python client on my macbook pro and the server is a linux desktop I have.

I am able to ssh into my linux box with as following:

```
ssh username@address.hopto.org
```

And then entering my password

Despite being able to ssh with no problem, I cannot get a port/socket connection to work.

Here is my python code:

```
import socket, time

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('username@address.hopto.org', 9999))
print client.send('Hello world!'), 'bytes sent.'
time.sleep(0.2)
print 'Received message:', client.recv(1024)
```

And here is my C++ server (which has been borrowed from this site: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part2/chap6/simple-server.c )

```
#define MY_PORT     9999
#define MAXBUF      1024

int main(int Count, char *Strings[])
{   int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in self;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];

    /*---Create streaming socket---*/
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Initialize address/port structure---*/
    bzero(&self, sizeof(self));
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /*---Assign a port number to the socket---*/
    if ( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--bind");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Make it a "listening socket"---*/
    if ( listen(sockfd, 20) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Forever... ---*/
    while (1)
    {   
        int clientfd;
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);
        printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

        /*---Echo back anything sent---*/
        send(clientfd, buffer, recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0), 0);

        /*---Close data connection---*/
        close(clientfd);
    }

    /*---Clean up (should never get here!)---*/
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I've actually tried two separate things for the python/client side:

If I write the following:

```
client.connect(('username@address.hopto.org', 9999))
```

I get this error:
**socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known**

However if I do:

```
client.connect(('address.hopto.org', 9999))
```

without the username part...I get this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I'm thinking it's because I have a password on my Linux box that is "blocking" the connection but I don't know how to include it here.

I'm a beginner at networking code so a lot of this is very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: The connection address will be an ip address (127.0.0.1) or a DNS name (address.hopto.org).  The @ notation is for emails.   You can telnet address.hopto.org 9999 to see if the server is up.  Try it on the box local to the server as well as the remote box.   You can also look at netstat -alnp | grep 9999 on the server box.  You are looking for a LISTEN notation.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused usually means the host is reachable but the port is not opened.
May be your request is block by firewall or your server is not running correctly.

To avoid the firewall issue. I suggest u can run your python script on same box as the server and use 127.0.0.1 to connect it first.